# 'Call to a member function get() on a non-object'?

Tags: php, symfony

Using symfony2. I have a listener class that is attempting to call a method from a different class (a controller) like so:

```
        $authenticate = new AuthenticationController();
        $authenticate->isTokenValid($token);
```

And the controller isTokenValid method:

```
public function isTokenValid($token) {

    $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
```

Is throwing the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/content/24/9254124/html/newsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 246
```

If i load the controller method the proper way (using routing in the url) it works fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit excuse me?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just dont understand what you mean by it is all..

Comment: http://www.eelis.net/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml -- good debugging technique includes making a testcase for yourself _before_ asking the internet for help! The process of making a testcase more often than not identifies the problem.

Comment: You might find this insightful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symfony2 uses Dependency Injection pattern, you have to inject container that holds all services (like database connection):

```
$authenticate = new AuthenticationController();
$authenticate->setContainer($this->container);
$authenticate->isTokenValid($token);
```

Of course I assume here that your listener class is `ContainerAware`

[+] To make your listener ContainerAware, pass `@service_container` to it (example form `services.yml`)

```
my.listener:
    class: ACME\MyBundle\ListenerController
    arguments: [ @service_container ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
    kernel.event_listener:
        event: kernel.controller
```

and then in constructor of you listener class:

```
public function __construct($container = null){
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Comment: Actually, i dont think its containeraware, it threw the error `undefined property: $container`..

Comment: Nice. I see what you mean now. Is `[ @service_container ]` literal, or should i be replacing that with something? Excuse my lack of understanding what a container is..

Comment: If you are using yml files for config, it is literally `@service_container`, if you are using something else, please refer to the documentation to see how you should define your listener

Comment: **-1** for suggesting to inject the whole container.

Comment: @elnur as far as I understand OP question this class also works as standard controller, so it doesn't make sense to double functionality, one using container and other using only db connection

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding another answer because what @dev-null-dweller suggests is a bad practice: in almost every case you better to inject only the services you need — not the whole container:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

public function __construct(Connection $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

```
my_listener:
    arguments: [ @database_connection ]
```