# Symfony 2 : How to render a template outside a controller or in a service?

Tags: symfony

How to render a template outside a controller or in a service?

I've been following the documentation of Symfony2. [Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#core-symfony-and-third-party-bundle-services)

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Newsletter;

use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class NewsletterManager
{
    protected $mailer;

    protected $templating;

    public function __construct(
        \Swift_Mailer $mailer,
        EngineInterface $templating
    ) {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is where i call my helper :

```
$transport = \Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$helper = new MailHelper($mailer);
$helper->sendEmail($from, $to, $subject, $path_to_twig, $arr_to_twig);
```

So the first thing here missing is the second parameter of the construct method in :

```
$helper = new MailHelper($mailer);
```

But how would i instantiate the EngineInterface?

Of course it can't be :

```
new EngineInterface();
```

I'm totally lost here.

All what i need to do is render a template for the email that is being sent.

Comment: Do you remember my gist from your latesr question? It is all there: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/4eea317ade72a119a72e

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inject only @twig and pass the rendered template to the mailer body:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\ContractBundle\Event;

use Acme\Bundle\ContractBundle\Event\ContractEvent;

class ContractListener
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function onContractCreated(ContractEvent $event)
    {
        $contract = $event->getContract();

        $body = $this->renderTemplate($contract);

        $projectManager = $contract->getProjectManager();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Contract ' . $contract->getId() . ' created')
            ->setFrom('noreply@example.com')
            ->setTo('dev@example.com')
            ->setBody($body)
        ;
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }

    public function renderTemplate($contract)
    {
        return $this->twig->render(
            'AcmeContractBundle:Contract:mailer.html.twig',
            array(
                'contract' => $contract
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay let me try again. I did try with Twig_Environment but i have some problem to reset the loader. i'm gonna try again and get back to you.

Comment: I suppose because i'm trying to use this as a service and not an event listener so i have to call the service that way (if i use \Twig_Environment). $helper = new MailHelper($mailer, new  \Twig_Environment); 
it returns : You must set a loader first. Is it really necessary?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the way a service is loaded. Check the symfony docs. Give your service a name, call it e.g. via container. That way mailer and twig will automatically injected to the Service constructor.

Comment: Okay it is way more clear! Thank you so much for your time. I was indeed not calling the service in the right way. $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('mail_helper'); was the right way.

Comment: How I have to pass $twig from controller?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean @KARTHEESWARAN . But if you want to get $twig inside the controller and pass it somewhere then you can get it using the AbstractController via $this->get('twig') depending on your symfony version. But it is a better practice to inject directly to the place e.g. a service where you need it.

Comment: Twig_Environment became deprecated. Use Twig\Environment now