# Having a custom repository with DBAL connection in Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to inject default DBAL connection into a custom repository associated with a entity so I can do some raw sql query.

In services.mxl

```
<service id="acme.repository.document" class="Acme\Bundle\Repository\DocumentRepository">
      <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
      <argument>Acme\Bundle\Entity\Document</argument>
      <argument type="service" id="database_connection" />
</service>
```

In my repository class DocumentRepository.php

```
class DocumentRepository extends EntityRepository {

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($em, $class, Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
         parent::__construct($em,$class);
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Acme\Bundle\Repository\DocumentRepository::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, none given, called in
>   /project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on
>   line 689 and defined in
>   /project/src/Acme/Bundle/Repository/DocumentRepository.php line 18

May you help me?

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of hours continue search for the optimal answer. I found the answer of [Elnur Abdurrakhimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745188/elnur-abdurrakhimov) is the best one (in my opinion, and my use cases).

**Source**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12908748/1617890

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

public function __construct(Connection $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

```
my_listener:
    arguments: [ @database_connection ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the connection from $_em attribute of EntityRepository class so here is how you could do it;

```
$connection = $this->_em->getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

`EntityRepository` in Doctrine ORM [is built internally](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L756). You can still define your own service, which can be a repository too, and then use that one. That's a limitation of the ORM since Doctrine does not use service location or dependency injection containers internally.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you aren't passing the correct instance of Connection, try this:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

class DocumentRepository extends EntityRepository 
{

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($em, $class)
    {
        $this->conn = $this->myHandleConnection();
         parent::__construct($em,$class);
    }

    public function myHandleConnection()
    {
        $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
        $connectionParams = array(
                'dbname' => 'MY_DB',
                'user' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                );
        $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
        return $conn;
    }
}
```