# Symfony2 "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in.." when call service in controller

Tags: symfony, service, controller

I have 2 controllers that use a same service:

CONTROLLER 1

```
    namespace MO\FrontendBundle\Controller;
    use MO\FrontendBundle\Controller\SuperClass\MOSearchController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

    class ResultsController extends MOSearchController {

         public function detailAction() {

              $vm = $this->get("vehicles_manager"); // SERVICE IN QUESTION

              $result = $vm->getVehicleDetail($idVehicle);

         }

    }
```

CONTROLLER 2

```
namespace MO\FrontendBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MetatagsController extends Controller {

     public function metatagsController() {

          $vm = $this->get("vehicles_manager"); // SERVICE IN QUESTION

          $result = $vm->getVehicleDetail($idVehicle);

     }

}
```

The service is regularly declared in services.yml file:

```
services:
    vehicles_manager:
        class: MO\FrontendBundle\Service\VehiclesManager
        arguments: [@logger, %vehicles_manager.endpoint%, %vehicles_manager.scope%, %vehicles_manager.consumer%, %form_values.manual_gear_code%]
        tags:
             - { name: monolog.logger, channel: solrws }

    vehicles_memory:
        class: MO\FrontendBundle\Service\VehiclesMemory
        arguments: [@request_stack]
```

The problem is that while in the first controller there are no errors, in the second i get the error:

*Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\Users\d.test\workspace\test\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php on line 274*

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905191/call-to-a-member-function-get-on-a-non-object

Comment: Can you post your routes?  It almost seems like you tried to define your second controller as a service but forgot to inject the container?  What is the code from line 274 in the framework controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second controller you didn't suffix the method name with Action then, it is not really an end point.
your code for the second controller should be:

```
namespace MO\FrontendBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

 class MetatagsController extends Controller {

  public function metatagsAction() {

      $vm = $this->get("vehicles_manager"); // SERVICE IN QUESTION

      $result = $vm->getVehicleDetail($idVehicle);

  }

}
```